# IQueryable<T> extension method to take data in batches

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Has anyone found/coded extension method that query data (using **linq to sql**) in batches? I've seen IEnumerable extensions but I'm looking for something I might use like this:

```
IQueryable<Order> orders = from i in db.Orders select i;
foreach(var batch in orders.InBatches(100))
{
   //batch of 100 products
   foreach(var order in batch)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Linq-2-sql for batches. In general, it is not designed to do that. Even if your // do something would go in batch and it would be an update of one field, still you would get 100 individual update statements sent to your DB after submitchanges. My advise is in your case to use a stored procedure (and I am a Linq-2-sql fan by the way)

Comment: thanks but my code does only query, not update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you can do is this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IQueryable<T>> InBatches(
    this IQueryable<T> collection, int size)
{  
    int totalSize = collection.Count();

    for (int start = 0; start < totalSize; start += size)
    {
        yield return collection.Skip(start).Take(size);
    }
}
```

This extension method allows you to do extra filters over the return IQueryables. However, the usefulness is pretty limited. I can't think of any good scenario for this :-). In most scenario's you just want to stream the results and returning an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` would just do fine, and is even better, since this will result in a single SQL query, while the shown approach will result in N + 1 queries.

Comment: believe me in my scenario I need n+1 queries aproach

Comment: It is really useful when you want to make operations on all records of a table (for example, you added a new column, and in production you want to populate with the adequate value). Then you don't want to make a single query, to get all the data, since it might time out because of the large quantity. Therefore you make queries in batches, and make your update in more steps, but without timeouts :)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) and [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx)? These are the LINQ operators for getting batches off an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` (and their non-generic counterparts).

Comment: nothing except I need to count records first and then make loop. I asked for extension method that I could reuse

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the batches themselves and you just want to break up connections for size or transaction purposes you can do the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> InBatches<T>(this IQueryable<T> collection, int batchSize)
{
    int start = 0;
    int records = 0;
    IQueryable<T> batch;

    // For the first batch
    start -= batchSize;

    do {
        records = 0;
        start += batchSize;
        batch = collection.Skip(start).Take(batchSize);

        foreach (T item in batch) {

            records += 1;
            yield return item;
        }

    } while (records == batchSize);
}
```